# If number of files in folder less than x then copy more files to folder

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I have a folder with around 1 million files that needs to be transferred in batches of 300 to a staging folder for upload to an S3. The files need to be moved in order of creation date oldest > newest.

I have created a script that does everything I need with only do one file at a time as a test. Now that im ready to do the batches, I seem to have hit a wall, as I cannot figure out how to do 300 at a time.

The workflow should go as such:

1. If destination folder is empty
2. find the 300 oldest file(s) in the source folder/or single oldest if using a loop
3. move file(s) to the destination folder
4. execute the S3 transfer (which deletes all files in destination
   folder)
5. Go back to step 1

Id rather do a batch of 300 at a time, but I was not able to find any information on how to specify an amount of files per 'batch' and I think having an additional function of needing the oldest first complicates things, so I believe a loop is in order

The code below will move the oldest file from the source folder to the destination folder 1 at a time

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

src = "Source Folder"
dst = "Destination Folder"

def oldest_file_in_tree(rootfolder, extension=".xml"):
    return min(
        (os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootfolder)
        for filename in filenames
        if filename.endswith(extension)),
        key=lambda fn: os.stat(fn).st_mtime)

oldest_xml = oldest_file_in_tree("Source Folder", '.xml')
shutil.move(oldest_xml, dst)
```

I've tried a few different loops/if statements - and they only seem to copy one file and then finish eg:

```
if files_in_dst <= 11:
    shutil.move(oldest_xml, dst)
```

```
dstCount = 0

for files in src:
    dstCount += 1
    shutil.move(oldest_xml, dst)
    if dstCount == 11:
        break
```

```
dstFolderCount = sum(len(files)for _, _, files in os.walk(dst))
while dstFolderCount < 11:
    oldest_xml = oldest_file_in_tree(Source Folder", '.xml')
    shutil.move(oldest_xml, dst)
```

I think the step I'm missing is how to actually get the loop to iterate, so if there is any reading/advice out there - im all ears.

Comment: what is `dstFolderCount` in your last code?

Comment: Sorry, missed a bit of code, i've edited the post.

Comment: the way you count number of files in `dstFolderCount`, it counts folders and subfolders in destination folder. Do you have other files except for these in destination folder?

Comment: No, its only the xml files, and once each batch of files is uploaded to S3, they are deleted from the destination folder essentially making it 'empty' each cycle

Comment: could you replace your while statement with `while len(glob.glob1(dst,"*.xml")) < 301:` in your last example

Comment: Sure, will give it a go cheers

Comment: @BijayRegmi - with a few tweaks, I got it to work - thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @BijayRegmi

Short Answer is using Blob to count the files in directory, then execute while loop.

```
while len(glob.glob1(Destination Folder,"*.xml")) < 5:
    try:
        #Insert Code Here#
    except(FileExistsError):
        print("File Exists")
```